# How to create a Mule Project v3.8 which redirects messages to an external Web Service?

Tags: wsdl, mule

I would like to create a Mule Project, and the idea is to send a SOAP message (for example through soapUI) to this project, and then, redirect the message to an external web service.
I have read the documentation, I can't figure out how to do this simple task.

I would appreciate if someone could help me. I am using Mule v3.8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Web Service Consumer` connector as explained at [MuleSoft Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/web-service-consumer) and [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2zRvbEQUEc)

Answer (score -1):

In general,
You can use:
HTTP endpoint (request-response) ->
CXF component (for you proxy service, optional) ->
Web Service Consumer (to call needed service)

If I'm not very clear, I can help you in building this project.

**update**
I made a simple service and now we have wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="SimpleServiceService" targetNamespace="http://simple/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://simple/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://simple/" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://simple/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="doSomething" type="tns:doSomething"/>
            <xs:element name="doSomethingResponse" type="tns:doSomethingResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="doSomething">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Input" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="doSomethingResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="doSomethingResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:doSomethingResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="doSomething">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:doSomething" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SimpleService">
        <wsdl:operation name="doSomething">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:doSomething" name="doSomething"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:doSomethingResponse" name="doSomethingResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SimpleServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:SimpleService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="doSomething">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="doSomething">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="doSomethingResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SimpleServiceService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:SimpleServiceServiceSoapBinding" name="SimpleServicePort">
            <soap:address location="http://exoldy-simple-mule-project.cloudhub.io/service"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Next we need to interact with this service using proxy service implemented on Mule

```
<mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd">

    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="SimpleServiceService" port="SimpleServicePort" serviceAddress="http://exoldy-simple-mule-project.cloudhub.io/service" wsdlLocation="http://exoldy-simple-mule-project.cloudhub.io/service?wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

    <flow name="external" initialState="started">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="service" doc:name="Receive HTTP request" doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message."/>
        <logger message="#[flow.name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service payload="body" doc:name="CXF" namespace="http://simple/" service="SimpleServiceService" wsdlLocation="http://exoldy-simple-mule-project.cloudhub.io/service?wsdl"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="doSomething" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Now everything should work, at least it works for me )

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain it a little more! I am reading the documentation but I can't make it work.

Thanks

Comment: @JuanAndrésLaCruz I updated the message, I hope it will be useful for you